# VMWare Server 1.0.7 on 64-bit Windows 2008 Issue

Tags: windows, 64-bit, vmware-server

Normally when using VMWare Server 1.0.7 you are asked if you would like to connect to the local machine or a remote host.  Installing the same software on 64-bit Windows 2008 only gives the remote host option.

I have tried entering the local machine name as the host and entering creds that have admin rights to the server but I just get a "Cannot connect as the target machine actively rejected it" error.  I have tried to find a solution on Google, but with no joy.

Anyone run into this before and can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem the drivers for VMWare Server 1.0.7 are unsigned and 64-bit windows refuses to load them.  Prior to security update KB932596 you could disable this check, but they have now stopped this.

I have previously tried VMWare Server 2, but have not found it that stable.

Running out of ideas......

Answer (score 0):

Had to install VMWare Server 2 in the end, no other option found.